# How can I detect when an element scrolls into the viewport using in-view.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am building a one-page website where I need to detect when an element scrolls into view. Essentially trying to build a black/white colour changing menu based on the opposite of the element's background color.

I found a javascript utility called [in-view](https://github.com/camwiegert/in-view) that seems to do what I want. But there are issues;

1. It works when scrolling down... but...
2. It wont work when scrolling back up. This is due to giving it an offset of the window height (because I want it to trigger once it reaches the menu).
3. Panels < height of the page don't trigger the plugin when you reach the bottom.

This is my JS code:

```
var winHeight = $(window).height()-75;
inView.offset(winHeight);
inView('.panel-content')
    .on('enter', function(el){
        var color = $(el).attr('data-color');
        if (color === 'dark') {
            $('#masthead').removeClass('light').addClass('dark');
        } else if (color === 'light') {
                $('#masthead').removeClass('dark').addClass('light');
        } else {
                $('#masthead').removeClass('light').addClass('dark');
        }
    });
```

...and this is the structure of my HTML:

*Note the panel height depend on content but vary from about 400 – 900.*

```
<div id="masthead">logo, nav etc...</div
<div class="panel-content" data-color="light" style="background-colour:#222"></div>
<div class="panel-content" data-color="dark" style="background-colour:#ddd"></div>
<div class="panel-content" data-color="dark" style="background-colour:#ddd"></div>
<div class="panel-content" data-color="light" style="background-colour:#222"></div>
<div class="panel-content" data-color="dark" style="background-colour:#ddd"></div>
<div class="panel-content" data-color="light" style="background-colour:#222"></div>
<div class="panel-content" data-color="dark" style="background-colour:#ddd"></div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Comment: Wow. A very good question IMO (and the first I've seen in a while `;)`)

Comment: Thanks @ItamarG3 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I first tried detecting the scroll direction; so if scrolling down the page set the offset to the window height, otherwise set offset to 0... – and that worked.

The need to detect the direction led me back to the [in-view documentation](https://github.com/camwiegert/in-view#inviewoffsetoffset) because I thought there had to be a better way. Turns out you can also specify an object containing the bounds (top, right, bottom, left), otherwise it uses the single value for each values! Which explains why I had the issues.

My final JS code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $target = $('#masthead');
    var winHeight = $(window).height()-1; //1px less so it triggers using nav links
    inView.offset({
        top: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: winHeight,
        left: 0
    });
    inView('.panel-content')
        .on('enter', function(el){
            var color = $(el).attr('data-color');
            if (color === 'dark') {
                $target.removeClass('light').addClass('dark');
            } else if (color === 'light') {
                $target.removeClass('dark').addClass('light');
            } else {
                $target.removeClass('light').addClass('dark');
            }
    });
});
```

- note that the HTML is as before.

Hope this helps others who are trying to achieve a similar colour changing nav, or similar.